# Python csv filter numbers in the form 1234 the same as 3241, 4321, 2143, 4213, etc?

Tags: python, excel, csv, numbers, filtering

I have a csv file with 4-digits numbers.

I want to find numbers which have the same 4 digits. The order of digits is not important. For example, 1234, 4321, 3214, and every number that is made from those 4 digits, should be filtered out as a group.

How can I do it using python or excel?

Thank you.

Comment: Please share a sample input, and also the code that you have tried so far

Comment: `if set(str(number1)) == set(str(number2)): # do things`

Comment: Thanks. The code `if set(str(number1)) == set(str(number2)): # do things` is correct in python. A VBA (Visual Basic for Application) code that sorts digits in number is also a good approach, which was just figured out.